# Как забилдить очень старый проект

Tags: java, android

Добрый день, есть проект следующей иерархии 
[image: 1]]

Как можно получить билд этого проекта исходя из иерархии?

Comment: Есть build.xml - попробуйте собрать ant-ом. Есть Makefile - попробуйте сделать make.

Comment: Пробовал собрать через make, выдает ошибки о несуществующем репозитории (логично, учитывая, что проект 12го года). А вот с ANT сейчас попробую

Comment: ваш вопрос примерно аналогичен ситуации: «пришли вы в сервисный центр, показываете фотоснимок телевизора, и спрашиваете: как бы сделать так, чтобы телевизор заработал?»

Comment: @alexander А теперь вы смоделируйте для себя следующую ситуацию: "Я приношу вам фотоснимок телевизора и спрашиваю, какой он марки и как его включать".  Вопрос состоит в том, как данный проект вообще можно собрать ? Лично про ANT я забыл, так как очень давно им не пользовался, а ответ который мне дали выше в комментариях, помог.